# Conjugate subgroups of permutation groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

[image]

To tackle this problem, does it not suffice to use the fact that two permutations are conjugate in $S_n$ if they have different cycle structure?For suppose that $\pi_1,\pi_2$ are two partitions as above, then is it not clear that if we consider the "maximal cycles" they must have different size orbits which should be preserved under conjugation?

To be more formal, $S_\pi \simeq \prod_{i=1}^{r} S_{p_i}$ (Direct product of permutation groups) so let $\sigma \in S_\pi$ be the element $(1 2 \ldots p_1) (p_1 +1 \ldots p_1 + p_2) \cdots)$ the "maximal product of cycles". Then is it not clear that for a different partition must have different sized cycles and thus orbits?

Comment: You clearly have a sound understanding of the problem. Consider asking when $S_\pi\subseteq S_\lambda$ in terms of refinements of partitions (breaking a block of the partition into two smaller blocks). Partitions are partially ordered by refinement. Containing the "maximal product of cycles element" is basically all that needs to happen.

Comment: @AlexR Can you clarify what you mean by "needs to happen"? My point here is that even if one is not a subset of the other, two different partitions must have different maximal cycles and thus cannot be conjugate.

Comment: @AlexR In particular, the "larger" maximal cycle (less fine partition) cannot be written as a conjugate in the finer partition's group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, in every subgroup $S_{\pi}$ there exist a unique (up to conjugacy) element that has a minimal number of cycles. The partition determined by the cycles of that element is just $\pi$. So you get $\pi$ from  (the conjugacy class of ) $S_{\pi}$, as you said.

Comment: So because of this 1-1 mapping between this minimal number cycles and the partition I can just say that different partition means different minimal number cycle so these can't be conjugate?

Comment: @Anthony Peter: What you can say is: if the subgroups are conjugate like $\sigma S_{\pi} \sigma^{-1} = S_{\pi'}$ then $\sigma(\pi) = \pi'$ that is, the partition are conjugate. That cannot happen unless they are equal, if the partition are chosen to be "standard" like in the text ( $\sigma$ can still be $\ne 1$,,,)

Comment: @Anthony Peter: there is another way to recover the partition $\pi$ from $S_{\pi}$, in a way more natural, by taking the orbits of the action of $S_{\pi}$ on $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.

Comment: So does a proof that they are not conjugate proceed as follows: Given $pi \neq pi'$, we look at the "maximal cycle" defined as $(1 \, 2\, \ldots p_1)(p_1+1 \, \, \ldots p_1+p_2)\cdots$ and similarly for $\pi'$. Then, conjugacy $\sigma S_\pi \sigma^{-1} = S_{\pi'}$ implies $\sigma(\pi) = \pi'$ which cannot happen by the choices of partitions. Thus, the maximal cycles must have different cycle structures (different orbits) and since orbits are preserved under conjugation, the two subgroups are not conjugate?

Comment: is this a valid proof?

Comment: @Anthony Peter: yes, you say: if the subgroups are conjugate then those partitions have to be conjugate ( you use the permutations with the "fattest cycles") but if the partitions are conjugate , they have to be equal, because of the special choice of them. Therefore, : for different /$\pi$ $\pi'$ chosen like in the textbook, the subgroups are not conjugate.